# How is mt19937 prng exactly used for python random module functions?

Tags: python, random, mt19937

```
from random import *
seed(5489)
hex(getrandbits(32)) # '0xc9a0e034'
hex(getrandbits(32)) # '0x38feb21f'
```

I ran this with Python 3.8.2 (not that it should matter too much). This is not what I would expect from a MT19937 32 bit PRNG. To be exact, I was expecting values similar to the ones presented in this website: https://create.stephan-brumme.com/mersenne-twister/

What is Python doing differently from other languages? Is there a way that I could reproduce the bits generated by Python myself? (Also, how is the random() float from 0 to 1 generated, from the 32-bit word sized integers?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's seeding algorithm is nothing like the one the link uses.  The Twister has a massive state, and a seed of only 32 bits can only put it into a comparatively trivial number of its possible states.  Python's seeding algorithm uses every bit of arbitrarily large arguments.

To reproduce Python's seeding algorithm, you'd have to read the C code and emulate it yourself.  Nothing about it is defined.

Python's code to generate an IEEE double is the same as the `genrand_res53()` function in the Twister's original C code:

```
uint32_t a=genrand_uint32(self)>>5, b=genrand_uint32(self)>>6;
return PyFloat_FromDouble((a*67108864.0+b)*(1.0/9007199254740992.0));
```

In effect, the top 27 bits of one 32-bit Twister output are shifted left 26, and the top 26 bits of "the next" 32-bit Twister output fill in the lower 26 bits, giving a 53-bit value that's divided by 2.0**53.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It was helpful. I took a glance at the C code (haven't actually emulated just yet). The seeding algorithm seems to first seed normally (using OG algo) with a magic number 19650218U, and proceed to use a custom init function using all bits from whatever pyobject hashes to. What I'm slightly curious about is what happened on this date as hinted by the constant in the source code. Do you by chance have any clue?

Comment: Good question!  According to https://eprint.iacr.org/2005/165.pdf, "The constant 19650218 is the birthday of one of the authors,chosen without reason" :-)

Comment: Note that the C seed code isn't the whole story - you need to look at `random.py`'s `seed()`  too.  Seeding based on hashing is deprecated.  In the C code, you're missing the `PyLong_CheckExact()` path, which uses a (possibly giant) non-negative integer as-is, and the C `init_by_array()` is passed _all_ its bits.

Comment: I read the C code and I am stuck at the initialization. By following both the Wikipedia article and the C code, the 1st state variable should be 0 (and the next should be 1) if the seed 0 is used, however, seeding from 0 and passing version=1 don't make the 1st state variable 0. Why? Try it out: online-python.com/Pxp4KycsCj

Comment: Sorry, "the C code" is ambiguous. Whose C code, exactly? As the answer said, Python's seeding works differently from others, because allowing only 32 seed bits is too restrictive for a generator with such a large state. A 32-bit seed only allows reaching a tiny fraction of the possible initial states. There's no "standard" way to initialize the Twister Although the original authors released more than one seeding algorithm, because the original made it too easy to fall into initial states with an enormous number of 0 bits - even the all-0 state, which is an utterly useless fixed point.